# How to create a markup to embed reviewer's occupation, company and location?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <p itemprop="reviewBody">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a met
  </p>
  <p itemprop="author">Dr. Exaggerate</p>
  <small>CEO, Organisation, Country</small>
</div>
```

**How to add the correct item properties for reviewer's Occupation, Company and Location(specifically country)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **follow** the examples here (Useful):
https://schema.org/Person

`author` values are expected to be one of these types:

- Organization
- Person

We use `Person` properties to give more semantic data about the author.

#### Job title

https://schema.org/jobTitle

`<span itemprop="jobTitle">CEO</span>`

#### Works for

https://schema.org/worksFor (expected [Organization type](https://schema.org/Organization))

`<span itemprop="worksFor">Nike</span>`

#### Work Location

https://schema.org/workLocation
(or use `address` Property - related to your data).

```
<div itemprop="workLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Paris, France</span>,
</div>
```

### Full example

```js
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <p itemprop="reviewBody">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a met
  </p>
  <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
   <p itemprop="name">Dr. Chapaklal</p>
   <span itemprop="jobTitle">CEO</span>
   <span itemprop="worksFor">Nike</span>
   <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">
      20341 Whitworth Institute
      405 N. Whitworth
    </span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Paris, France</span>,
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]